# url parameter of ajax for specific function

Tags: php, jquery

i want to set url parameter of ajax to a function of class and return the value of that function but my problem it seems cant access to function and nothing returns

this is my script:

```
$('#send').click(function (e) { //event added
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent normal for submit
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'localhost/shapeproject/controllers/Square/getArea',
        data:{'edge':edge},
        success:(function (response) {
            alert(response);
        })
    });
});
```

this is my class:

```
<?php
class Square extends Shape
{
    private $edge;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->edge = $_POST['edge'];
    }

    public function getArea()
    {
        return $this->edge * $this->edge;
    }

    public function getPerimeter()
    {
        return $this->edge * 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a page and name it ajax_handle.php.
then link to that page in your ajax code like this

```
$('#send').click(function (e) { //event added
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent normal for submit
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'ajax_handle.php',
        data:{'edge':edge, getArea: true},
        success:(function (response) {
            alert(response);
        })
    });
});
```

now in your ajax_handle.php you can write this code.

```
if(isset($_POST['getArea']) && $_POST['getArea'] == true)
{
    $obj = new Square();
    $obj->getArea();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

but you don't set any data... Add `data` to the jquery function;

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'localhost/shapeproject/controllers/Square/getArea',
    data: { edge: 'xyz' },
    success:(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    })
});
```

Comment: post editted. i test it already with simple alert but problem is with url in ajax i think

Comment: I see you've edited your post, but it shouldn't be `{ 'edge': edge }` but the other way around, as the variable `edge` is not declared and as such will not be sent. just try the exact example I gave you and check dev tools if the variable is sent, and `print_r($_POST)` if it's received

Answer (score 0):

You must have a front controller to manage this process.

For example: create a file called `index.php` inside `shapeproject` directory.

Then you can extract controller and function names from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

You may need to use some `.htaccess` directives like the example below:

`RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php`

Read more about front controllers: [An Introduction to the Front Controller Pattern](https://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/)

Comment: could you tell me a fast and simple way

Comment: Done, I hope that could help you to understand how it works